# How exactly does VBO keep its content?

Tags: c, opengl, gpu

I've started learning and faced with some vagueness: I don't understand when we allocate memory for VBO?

I think we allocate memory when call `glBufferData`, but does it mean that we always keep a large bank of allocated memory independent of what VAO we bind? So I need to bind VAO only for attributes, just to tell GPU from which VBOs to take the data (that's already on the GPU) and how to interpret this data… and that's all the connection between VAO and VBO, only through attribs…

Comment: There are cases where you want several VBOs in a single VAO. And there are cases where the same buffer is used in different VAOS. Read [this good book](https://paroj.github.io/gltut/Positioning/Tutorial%2005.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VBO's are most likely (but not always!) allocated in memory on the GPU. glBufferData was until recently the only method to allocate memory on a VBO *(If you are using GL4.5, glBufferStorage is now the recommended way to allocate the memory)*. The data within a VBO is basically just a large blob of unknown stuff *(well, unknown to the GPU)*. From the CPU/main ram, we call glBufferData, and the GPU will allocate a chunk of memory to hold the data, and blindly copy the data from main ram to the GPUs ram. The GPU has no idea what it contains....

VAOs are simply a description of the memory layout of a buffer. Let's take an example...

- VBO1: this contains the vertex & normal data for a cube.
- VBO2: this contains the vertex & normal data for a sphere.

Let's assume that the normals & vertices are packed into a structure that looks like so:

```
struct VertexNormal {
  float vx, vy, vz;
  float nx, ny, nz;
};
```

In both cases, all of these are true:

- the vertex has an offset of 0
- the normal has an offset of 12 (i.e. 3 x sizeof(float))
- the stride for each vertex and normal element is 24 (6 x sizeof(float))

This information needs to be passed from the CPU to the GPU so that the GPU can correctly read data from the buffers into the vertex attributes when rendering. Without this information, the GPU just looks at the VBO as a blob of unknown stuff.

The way we pass this information to the GPU is via a VAO. The VAO stores the following information about a given vertex attribute that your shader needs:

- data type (GL_FLOAT, GL_INT, etc)
- number of elements (Vec2, Vec3, Vec4??)
- the stride between each element
- The buffer that contains that data [aka binding point]

This per-vertex information can get quite large for reasonably complex shaders, so it's not state we want to set up too often. This is where a VAO comes in. We create a VAO, and fill it with information about each input attribute to our vertex shader.

Given that our cube & sphere are probably rendered with the same shader, and that the vertex & normal data are the same in both buffers, we can make use of 1 VAO in this case (and just change the buffer[s] we are binding to with glVertexArrayVertexBuffers).